# table income and expense is better to have it together or apart

Tags: sql-server, database

I am developing a small system where I have to record incomes and expenses of the company, and even I can not determine if the income and expense table should be in one table or in separate tables.

The design of the database must allow the system to generate a report of income and expenses by date (in column incomes and other expenses).

I would like to explain what would be the advantage or disadvantage of having them together or separately.

Comment: It would be appropriate if you ask in other site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Horaciux Ok, I did not know existed dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they both store the same fields of information, there's no reason why you can't put them both in the same table with a field marked TransType that would be set to I for Income or E for Expense.  Or, you'd know the difference based on whether the value is greater than or less than zero.  This way, you could report them separately if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm imagining a single table with a transaction date, account, and amount.  The expenses would be negative and the incomes would be positive, but the best way to define incomes versus expenses would be the description of the account that the transaction is posted to.  There is no need to build a separate table for each since they are storing the same type of information, and you can easily just grab the income or just grab the expenses by looking at the sign of the amount field.  You could even include a type field to differentiate, if you wanted.